# How to read a bson file using C#

Tags: mongodb

I have a bson file dumped by `mongodump` command.

How can I read the content of this file to memory with C#??

I don't want to use the `mongorestore` command.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to study the BSON specs to create your own functions, or use one of the available libraries that others made already: http://bsonspec.org/implementations.html